# Install and run GAMS in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, gams-math

I want to use GAMS in Fedora (23). I have read the information on how to install GAMS in Unix (https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fuserguide%2F_u_g__i_n_s_t_a_l_l.html&cp=0_1).

I have downloaded the file to a folder and successfully ran:
 `chmod -x linux_x64_64_sfx.exe`

I try to run `~/linux_x64_64_sfx.exe` but could not, then tried

```
./linux_x64_64_sfx.exe
```

which I think is the fedora command. I get the following message:

```
UnZipSFX 5.52 of 28 February 2005, by Info-ZIP (http://www.info-zip.org).
replace gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libxprs.so.28.01.14? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

I typed A once, got a very big list of messages similar to the ones below:

```
inflating: gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/getNAnan.m  
  inflating: gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libgrbcclib64.so  
finishing deferred symbolic links:
  gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libcplex.so -> libcplex1263.so
  gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libgurobi.so -> libgurobi.so.6.5.2
```

Then nothing happend. I tried again running `./linux_x64_64_sfx.exe` got the same message, this time I typed in N, and got short message:

```
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libcplex.so exists and is a symbolic link.
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libgurobi.so exists and is a symbolic link.
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libxprs.so.28.01 exists and is a symbolic link.
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libxprl.so exists and is a symbolic link.
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libxprl.so.x7.9 exists and is a symbolic link.
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libxprs.so exists and is a symbolic link.
gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/libknitro.so.10 exists and is a symbolic link.
```

And nothing else happened.

How can I run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be provided as a self-extracting archive ("sfx" is a typical convention for referring to such archives; "exe" is a DOS/Windows thing, but looks like they just kept that to be consistent and it is a Linux binary).

The messages you are seeing come from that extraction. The fact that it says you are overwriting files in a `gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/` subdirectory strongly suggests that you *already* ran it, and are now doing the same thing again. It's telling you that the files are already there, and I bet if you do `ls gams24.7_linux_x64_64_sfx/`, you will see them.

The instructions you linked give

> 6. Change to the GAMS system directory and run the program `./gamsinst`.

... have you tried that?

Comment: That was it, thanks. For a detailed procedure this video might help others: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx_tYI3wyP4